# Search from current location in Word office add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Let's say you want to implement a custom search for a Word add-in to find the first instance of the word `foo` after the current position of the cursor.  You could do it this way:

1. Use `context.document.getSelection()` to get a `Range` of the cursor location.
2. Use `context.document.body.search('foo')` to get a list of Ranges with all instances of the word `foo`
3. Iterate over all of the foo Ranges, use `compareLocationWith()` to see if a foo Range is after the current location, and select the first foo Range that is after.
4. Use `Range.select()` to go the foo Range selected at step 3.

It seems that the above would work, but it is somewhat convoluted.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

you can do the required scenario in one line of code, shown below.

First you need to establish the search range, from the current position to the end of the document. (in this case i am assuming thats what you need, it can also be to the end of the current paragraph, for instance). We achieve this by expanding the current selection to the end of the document. Then we just do a search and get the first occurrence (by using the quite useful getFirst() method!) . then highlight it in yellow.

```js
 context.document.getSelection().expandTo(context.document.body.getRange("end")).search("foo").getFirst().font.highlightColor = "yellow";
```

you can play with my snippet in script lab:
https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/4810f8ec53e4fb77e6d24a0eee8537f2

Comment: Thanks Juan, this is great!  Is there also a one liner to search in reverse?  Or do you need to do this `matches = context.document.getSelection().expandTo(context.document.body.getRange("start")).search("foo")` and `matches.load("items")` and then process in a `then()` block?